# Convergent series by the Root Test

Tags: calculus

Determining the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3\left(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n\right)^n}{3^n}$$

Applying the Root Test: $$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^3\left(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n\right)}{3^n}}=\lim\sqrt[n]{n^3\cdot\left(\frac{(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n}{3}\right)^n}=\left(\lim n^{\frac{3}{n}}\right)\left(\limsup\frac{\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n}{3}\right)=\left(\lim n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\left(\limsup\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n\right)=\frac{1}{3}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n\right)<\frac{1}{3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3\right)=1$$

Therefore since $r<1$, the series converges. Is this correct?

Comment: Should be $\sqrt[n]{\dots}$ inside the limit. That is done by typing `\sqrt[n]{...}`

Comment: Thank you! I couldnt quite figure out how to do that! Will edit.

Comment: Also, it should really be $\limsup$ rather than limits, since $\lim \left(\sqrt 2 +(-1)^n\right)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: So should I include limsup only in the last line where I edited?

Comment: You need $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} <1.$ So, theoretically, you need $\limsup$ all the way through. You can ignore the absolutie value since all of the $a_n$ values are positive.

Answer (score 2):

It does converge
but your proof is not correct.

What you should write is
$\left|\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n}{3}\right|
\le \left|\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+1}{3}\right|
\lt 1
$
and this shows convergence.